# Difference in where clause - in and not in

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

There is some difference in the below two queries.

Query1:

```
select  distinct source from BUDGET where product_code in
                    (select distinct PRODUCT_CODE from BUDGET  where PRODUCT_CODE not in 
                                (select distinct PRODUCT_CODE from PRODUCT_MASTER)
                                                                            and PRODUCT_CODE not in 
                                (select distinct PRODUCT_CODE from CVM )
                                                                            and( VERSION_ID like '17%'
                                                                            or VERSION_ID like '18%')
                    )
```

Query 2:

```
select  distinct SOURCE  from BUDGET where PRODUCT_CODE not in 
                                (select distinct PRODUCT_CODE from PRODUCT_MASTER)
                                                                    and PRODUCT_CODE not in 
                                (select distinct PRODUCT_CODE from CVM )
                                                                    and( VERSION_ID like '17%'
                                                                        or VERSION_ID like '18%')
```

I want the source of the products whose product codes are not contained in both product_master and CVM. I try the above 2 queries. Both return different result set. Could someone help me figure out the difference in both the queries.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First query - find all `PRODUCT_CODE`s where (not in criteria match) and `VERSION_ID` matches certain criteria. Then, separately, find *all* rows in the `BUDGET` table that match those `PRODUCT_CODE`s and find all unique sources. Notably, *these* rows are not `VERSION_ID` constrained.

Second query - find all `SOURCE`s where (not in criteria match) and `VERSION_ID` matches certain criteria. This will not return `SOURCE` values for other rows which happen to have the same `PRODCUT_CODE` value but different `VERSION_ID` values.

Which one is correct I couldn't say. If we had sample data and expected results, and more *explanation* of your goal, it may be that neither of these queries currently matches your expectations.

(Also, note that using `DISTINCT` in an `IN()` query is at best a distraction to the optimizer and at worst a pessimisation. `IN()` should be able to return as soon as it identifies a single match. If you're unlucky, the optimizer will actually do the work to ensure that the results are unique but that doesn't affect the question of *whether a match exists or not*)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT source FROM  BUDGET WHERE  
product_code IN -- NOT IN
(
    SELECT PRODUCT_CODE  FROM PRODUCT_MASTER
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PRODUCT_CODE  FROM CVM 
)
AND VERSION_ID like '1[78]%'
```